# Is possible to the HockeyApp send crash reports only on WiFi connected

Tags: crash, crash-reports, hockeyapp

Is possible to the HockeyApp send crash reports only on WiFi connected

I need what Reports sends only if good connection like WiFi.

Comment: And you expect us to know what you're talking about?

Comment: @Dmitry, you should probably ask on the official HockeyApp support site, http://support.hockeyapp.net